# How to fetch data from table using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, fetch

Hello I have 3 table

**property** (Agent property)

**user** (Agent Details)

**user_property** (Union table of **property** and **user** table)

I'm trying to fetch my agent details using this code below.

```
 /* Fetch agent */

    $agent = $this->user_m->get_agent($this->data['property_id']);

    // [agent_direct feature]
    $standard_agent = true;
    if(config_db_item('agent_profile_direct') === TRUE)
    {
        $agent_direct = $this->session->userdata('agent_direct');
        $last_activity = $this->session->userdata('last_activity');

        if(is_array($agent_direct) && $agent_direct['id'] != $agent['id'])
        {
            $agent = $agent_direct;
            $standard_agent=false;
        }

    }
    // [/agent_direct feature]

    if(count($agent))
    {
        $this->data['agent_name_surname'] = $agent['name_surname'];
        $this->data['agent_phone'] = $agent['phone'];
        $this->data['agent_mail'] = $agent['mail'];
        $this->data['agent_address'] = $agent['address'];
        $this->data['agent_id'] = $agent['id'];
        $this->data['agent_name_title'] = url_title_cro($agent['name_surname']);
        $this->data['agent_url'] = slug_url('profile/'.$agent['id'].'/'.$this->data['lang_code'].'/'.$this->data['agent_name_title']);
    }

    $this->data['has_agent'] = array();
    if(count($agent))
        $this->data['has_agent'][] = array('count'=>count($agent));

    // Thumbnail
    if(count($agent) && isset($agent['image_user_filename']))
    {
        $this->data['agent_image_url'] = base_url('files/thumbnail/'.$agent['image_user_filename']);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->data['agent_image_url'] = 'assets/img/user-agent.png';
    }
```

But when I try to output agent details using pseudo variable it shows nothing..
Just a blank details

Here's my code below

> ```
> <div>
>               {has_agent}
>               <h2>{lang_Agent}</h2>
>               <div class="agent">
>
>
>                 <div class="image"><img src="{agent_image_url}" alt="{agent_name_surname}" /></div>
>                 <div class="name"><a href="{agent_url}#content">{agent_name_surname}</a></div>
>                 <div class="phone">{agent_phone}</div>
>                 <div class="mail"><a href="mailto:{agent_mail}?subject={lang_Estateinqueryfor}:
>                {estate_data_id}, {page_title}">{agent_mail}</a></div>
>
>               </div>
>               {/has_agent}
>   </div>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

syntax of fetching data from database table is following.

```
$this->db->get_where('tableName',array('columnName'=>'value'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Always try to used like this. Its very good coding and proper coding style.

```
$data['field_name'] = 'field_value';
$qry = $this->db->get_where('table_name',$data);
return $qry->result_array();
```